# In 毕业之后最开始在一家房地产公司做销售员，底薪一千八, why does 最开始 translate to "went to work"?

Tags: translation

In this sentence:

> 毕业之后最开始在一家房地产公司做销售员，底薪一千八。

The translator apparently translated "最开始" as went to work.  Here is the translation:

> after I graduated I first went to work as sales staff at a real estate agency with a salary of 1,800

Why does 最开始 translate to "went to work"?

I am confused because I can't find any thing that relates 最开始 with finding a job.  I think "最开始" means initially or at first. But then, where is the character for "to work" in 在一家房地产公司做销售员?

Comment: 做 can mean "act/work as"  thus 做销售员 "work as sales clerk", in connection with 最开始 the meaning seems to agree with "first go to work as sales clerk"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 毕业之后**最开始**在一家房地产公司做销售员,底薪一千八
>
> after I graduated I **first** went to work as sales staff at a real estate agency with a salary of 1,800

[在一家房地产公司] {做销售员} -> (went to) {work as sales staff} [at a real estate agency].

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know "做" means to work. Did the "在一家房地产公司" come first because in Chinese the location needs to be written first ?

Comment: @Cheeseu, yes, that's kind of convention of Chinese sentence ordering. Eg. 我在中国工作. 我工作在中国 is not natural, but understandable.

Comment: "after I graduated I (first ) went ...  " =  "我毕业之后(首先)..."

Comment: @TangHo, I noticed that it's a loose translation. I was just trying to get OP out of his confusion. On the other hand, I think the original translation is ok, but certainly has a room for improvement.

Answer (score 2):

[毕业之后] = After graduated

[**最开始**] = **at the very beginning** /**in the initial stages** (*of my career*)

[在一家房地产公司做销售员] = I worked as a sales staff in a real estate agency

[底薪一千八] = with base salary of 1,800  (*I am sure his main income was commissions*)

- "毕业之后在一家房地产公司做销售员" is already a complete sentence. "最开始" is a relative phrase that give us additional information, pinpointing the exact time - 'at the very beginning'
- 做 here means "being/ assume the role of/ act as"